# Clipboard Tool to Paste Several Version Back

Tags: windows-vista, clipboard

I'm working on migrating some Flash files from AS2 to AS3, and I'm realizing that there are several pieces of text that I need to copy over and over and over.

Right now I have those pieces of text in an open notepad file, but I would love to have the ability to store those pieces in a clipboard so I can easily access them like by pushing something like CTRL+1, CTRL+2, etc.

Does anyone know of a good tool to do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

If you have visual studio installed you can use that instead of notepad. Then you can copy multiple strings to clipboard and use Ctrl+Shift+Ins to paste them one by one.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is Microsoft Office, here's a nice little [write-up](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word/HA101636021033.aspx) on their Clipboard utility.

It's also nice in that it's type agnostic, so you can clip multiple levels of text, images, whatever.  I haven't used the Visual Studio version so I don't know how it compares, but I use it all the time.